# Facebook Like button won't show on Azure website http

Tags: facebook, azure

I've got an azure website (at http://ekpowestore.azurewebsites.net/) that won't show a Facebook like button in Explorer or Firefox.  It does in Chrome and Safari.  Yet if I change the address to https (as in https://ekpowestore.azurewebsites.net/), the Like and Share buttons render just fine.

Liking an https isn't the same as http.  I guess I can refer folks to the https site, but I'm still curious about what the root cause is.

Of course, I tried about 100 different things before finally throwing up a nearly empty page on my azure site.

Comment: Could this be related to mixed site content? If I am not mistaken, Facebook's Like button is displayed via a plugin which is loaded using https request.

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav - I wasn't aware of this.  I just changed all my links to be protocol relative, and the problem remains.  I don't think all Facebook like sites need to be https, so there must be something else going on.  And why Chrome and Safari work while IE and FF don't, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

seems your page returns 307 "Internal Redirect" while trying to load the Facebook script on HTTP request. I am not sure, but you possibly used "Protocol relative" referencing on your javascript like

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

which will redirect the action with using the current protocol (https://connect.facebook.... if you are using HTTPS or to HTTP). Could you please try to replace it with full url to give it a try ?

eg.

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

Comment: Just tried that - Same result.  I think I'm going to just force Azure to redirect to https and call it a day...  Thanks for the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I give up.  This isn't the actual answer to the o.p., so I won't mark it as such.  But it is what I did to address the problem - So perhaps someone will find this useful.

Note that I did take the entire app down to just an html doc with a facebook like plugin in it - No other dependencies - And yet then still IE and FF no love, Safari and Chrome fine.  This was both using a protocol relative Facebook path (i.e. - "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js") and a specified https path (i.e. "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js")

So rather than fight the http - https mixed content war that Gaurav pointed out may have been happening with the Facebook reference, I changed the Azure site so it always forwards http to https.  Problem solved, moving on ('problem solved' being slightly different than 'question answered').

Added a web.config file consisting of the following worked for me:

````

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```